# mouseup event not firing when "dragging" an image in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found a couple similar questions, but all were related to buttons.  This is a little different.  In the example below, I get a `mouseup` after a `mousedown` on a non-image element.  However, when I `mousedown` an image element, I never receive the event.

```js
$(document).on('mousedown','.draggable', function() {
  console.log("Clicked " + $(this).data('type'));
});

$(document).on('mouseup','.dropzone', function(e) {
  console.log("Dropped");
});
```

```css
.dropzone {
 height: 100px;
 width: 200px;
 border: 1px solid blue;
 text-align: center;
}

div {
user-select: none;
}

.il {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="draggable il" data-type="image" src="https://imgur.com/xTFOquF.png">
<div class="draggable il" data-type="text">No, drag me!</div>
<div class="dropzone il">Drop stuff here</div>
```

How can I make it so I get a `mouseup` event after a `mousedown` on the image?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using `mouseup`, use html [drag and drop](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp), which was built for this purpose. All your draggable elements must have draggable=true set and you need to prevent default on the dragover and drop events.

```js
$(".draggable").on('mousedown', function(e) {
  console.log("Clicked " + $(this).data('type'));
});

$(".dropzone").on('drop', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();  
  console.log("Dropped");
});

$(".dropzone").on('dragover', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();  
});
```

```css
.dropzone {
 height: 100px;
 width: 200px;
 border: 1px solid blue;
 text-align: center;
}

div {
user-select: none;
}

.il {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="draggable il" draggable="true" data-type="image" src="https://imgur.com/xTFOquF.png">
<div class="draggable il" draggable="true" data-type="text">No, drag me!</div>
<div class="dropzone il">Drop stuff here</div>
```

If you need to use mouseup, you can just use `e.preventDefault()` on the mousedown event, but this will also prevent your browser from showing the drag.

```js
$(document).on('mousedown','.draggable', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("Clicked " + $(this).data('type'));
});

$(document).on('mouseup','.dropzone', function(e) {
  console.log("Dropped");
});
```

```css
.dropzone {
 height: 100px;
 width: 200px;
 border: 1px solid blue;
 text-align: center;
}

div {
user-select: none;
}

.il {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="draggable il" data-type="image" src="https://imgur.com/xTFOquF.png">
<div class="draggable il" data-type="text">No, drag me!</div>
<div class="dropzone il">Drop stuff here</div>
```

You can also set `draggable=false` on the image to have this same effect